# How to read all lines of an csv file from HttpContent in C#

Tags: c#, csv, encoding, stream, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create somo c# objects from an excel file read in from form data. It works if I first store it as a file and then use:

```
File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(x => x.Split(','))...
```

However, I want to read it straight off the Stream from the HttpContent. When I try this, I get encoding issues.

```
    private const int WIN_1252_CP = 1252; // Windows ANSI codepage 1252    

    public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Func<Stream> streamProvider,
                                 Encoding encoding)
    {
        using (var stream = streamProvider())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                   yield return line;

            }
        }
    }
```

In web api action:

```
       ... 
       HttpContent file1 = files[0];

       Stream input = await file1.ReadAsStreamAsync();
       var listData = ReadLines(() => input,
                 Encoding.GetEncoding(WIN_1252_CP)).ToList();
```

I get the correct number of lines, but the encoding does not work.

Edit: In hindsight, I was being foolish and this would have worked with the utf-8 encoding. However, the answer gives a tidier way of implementing this functionality, so I hope it will still be useful

Comment: This sounds more like trying to read a flat file (csv) as apposed to an excel file? Clarify the confusion.

Comment: Why do you provide custom encoding? Have you tried not to pass encoding?

Comment: @Nkosi Good point. I am trying to pass a csv, sorry for the confusion. I will update the question.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov I have tried not passing the encoding and I get the same issue

Comment: @Sam Why not use `ReadAsStringAsync` on the http content and then split by new line? That would be equivalent to file read all lines.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, you're a star!

Comment: @Nkosi, can you explain why StreamReader didn't work? Sam, have you tried with UTF-8 encoding which is default for HTTP?

Comment: @Nkosi in truth, I was having a dumb moment and selecting the xslt file instead of the csv. Whoever downvoted, fair enough, I deserve that one. Still, your answer is very helpful!! I will probably edit the question slightly soon to make it simpler to follow.

Comment: For reading/writing CSV look at http://filehelpers.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how it was read from the saved file use `ReadAsStringAsync` on the http content and then split by new line? That would be equivalent to file read all lines.

```
HttpContent file1 = files[0];
var input = await file1.ReadAsStringAsync();
var data = input.Split(Environment.NewLine)
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(x => x.Split(','))...
```

The framework will take care of what ever encoding needs to be handled from the stream so that it is no longer a concern of the developer.